# Serial key generation xor string encryption

Tags: c#, string, xor, key-generator

When I do an **xor** on a `string` I get special characters

```
private void btnEncryptDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyTextBox.Text);
        textTextBox.Text = string.Empty;

        foreach (byte i in bytes)
        {
            byte c = Convert.ToByte(i ^ Convert.ToByte(textBox1.Text));

            textTextBox.Text = textTextBox.Text + Convert.ToChar(c);

        }         

    }
```

`62FA7AC4 1234567890` **xor** to `!%QV VT#7&%$#"! /.'`

I want to use it for *serial key generation* with only alphanumeric characters 
I want to pass `"62FA7AC4"`, a `date` and a `number` between `0` and `5000` and a few random dummy numbers

**Input** will be `"62FA7AC4"+"2500"+"21/05/2018"`

**Output** should be something like `"5QBK-J4D1-8CF6-5MW2-78FZ-2FPL-4S6S-CTGB"`

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: There are some good tutorials [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28550/Protecting-Your-Software-Using-Simple-Serial-Numbe) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116455/Simple-Application-For-Creating-Serial-Number-Base) that do a good job explaining how to make these.

Comment: @Icemanind The first "here" is not c# and the second "here" doesn't work... keep getting errors when I run it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try working with *numbers*, not *strings*:

```
  using System.Numerics;

  ... 

  // Let's use BigInteger for arbitrary long values
  BigInteger left = BigInteger.Parse("62FA7AC4", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
  BigInteger right = BigInteger.Parse("1234567890", NumberStyles.HexNumber);

  string result = (left ^ right).ToString("X");

  Console.Write(result);
```

So you have

```
  1256AC0254
```

**Edit**: As far as I can see you want alphanumeric (i.e. **Base 36** == `26` *letters* + `10` *digits* output). You can use the same approach: operate with integer(s), not string(s)

```
  private static Random s_Random = new Random();

  ...

  BigInteger value = BigInteger.Parse(
      "0"        +                             // we don't want negative values  
      "62FA7AC4" +                             // header 
       s_Random.Next(5001).ToString("0000") +  // random in [0..5000] range
       DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy"),    // Date like 21052018
    NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Then do any xor (if you like):

```
 value ^= some_secret_value;
```

Finally *represent* the `value` in `base 36`:

```
private static String ToBase36(BigInteger value) {
  List<char> list = new List<char>();

  for (int index = 0; value > 0; value /= 36, index++) {
    if (index > 0 && index % 4 == 0)
      list.Add('-');

    BigInteger v = value % 36;

    list.Add(v < 10 ? (char)('0' + v) : (char) ('A' + v - 10));
  }

  list.Reverse();

  return string.Concat(list);
}
```

Test:

```
 BigInteger value = BigInteger.Parse(
    "0" + 
    "62FA7AC4" + 
    "2500" + 
     DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), 
   NumberStyles.HexNumber);

 string result = ToBase36(value);

 Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
2443-WNC5-AVBB-M32W
```

**Edit 2**: To restore the original number

```
private static BigInteger FromBase36(string value) {
  BigInteger result = 0;
  BigInteger power = 1;

  for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    char item = value[i];

    if (item >= '0' && item <= '9') {
      result += power * (item - '0');
      power *= 36;
    }
    else if (item >= 'A' && item <= 'Z') {
      result += power * (item - 'A' + 10);
      power *= 36;
    }
    else if (item >= 'a' && item <= 'z') {
      result += power * (item - 'a' + 10);
      power *= 36;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

e.g.

```
BigInteger value = BigInteger.Parse(
    "0"        + 
    "62FA7AC4" + 
    "2500" + 
     DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), 
   NumberStyles.HexNumber);

string result = ToBase36(value);

BigInteger back = FromBase36(result);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, value, result, back));
```

Outcome:

```
467412447575903165554712
2443-WNC5-AVBB-M32W
467412447575903165554712
```

Comment: I want to use it for serial key generation with only alphanumeric characters I want to pass "62FA7AC4", a date and a number between 0 and 5000 and a few random dummy numbers

Comment: @Vamp_102: Could you, please, provide some *examples*: what is passed as arguments and the desired outcome(s)

Comment: @Vamp_102: The same approach as far as I can see, but you should convert the final number into **base 36**. See my edit

Comment: Thank you, it works good... how do I Revers it on so I can validate it on the actual program?

Comment: BigInteger back = FromBase36(value);

 Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' to 'string'

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should have been `BigInteger back = FromBase36(result);`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: sorry for being a noob again... how do I get my original values from "back"?

eg. from 467412447575903165554712 to 62FA7AC4250021052018 ?

Comment: @Vamp_102: use *formatting*: `string myBackString = FromBase36(result).ToString("X");`, please, notice `"X"` which means "represent as hexadecimal value"

Comment: Thanks for the assistance ;)

Comment: Good Day... I know that it's been a while... I have been using this code but I encountered a problem... As you know the first 8 chars "62FA7AC4" is a HDD serial number... on some computers the output from "ToBase36(value)" is an empty string... for example when value = BigInteger.Parse("D475C503" + "2500" + DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy"),NumberStyles.HexNumber)

Comment: @Vamp_102: I see; you are getting *negative number* after pasring. Add *leading zero* to prevent it: `value = BigInteger.Parse("0" + "D475C503" + "2500" + DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy"),NumberStyles.HexNumber);`. Please, note `"0" + `

Comment: Thank you... Much appreciated